# Is there a word to describe the state of believing you know something that is false?

Tags: single-word-requests

When you do not know a fact you are ignorant.  My question is what would you call the state of   believing you know something that is false.

For instance suppose I see a black box and having opened it earlier, I know there is a rabbit in it.  Some time later unbeknownst to me someone   removes the rabbit.  I still 'know' there is a rabbit in the box.

What do you call this state?

Comment: There's always the [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Comment: Denial comes to mind.

Comment: I would call it a delusion, or deluded...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One word is ***mistaken***.

> *adjective*
>     wrong in one’s opinion or judgement:
>       *she wondered whether she’d been mistaken about his intentions*
>         based on or resulting from a misunderstanding or faulty judgement:
>           *don’t buy a hard bed in the mistaken belief that it is good for you*
>           *an unfortunate case of mistaken identity*
>
> [[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mistaken?q=mistaken)]

Comment: And, *pace* @Fortiter, a **mistaken** belief is easily proved to be wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Such a belief could be described as **erroneous**.  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erroneous) defines **erroneous** as "containing or characterized by error: mistaken."

Answer (score 3):

I think that this example is merely a matter of ignorance: the person who believes that there is a rabbit in the box is ignorant of the fact that the rabbit was removed and, therefore, continues to believe something that once was true but has since changed and become false.

A better word than *ignorant* and *mistaken*, I think, is one of these:

> [tricked, bamboozled, conned, deceived, duped, misled](http://thesaurus.com/browse/fooled?s=t)

Comment: All those words require deliberate action on the part of a third party, and while the OP's example does include that, it's not necessarily a required feature of the requested term.

Answer (score 3):

You believe that the rabbit is in the black box.

Answer (score 3):

Do I know that the sun will rise tomorrow?

I think that all I know is that there is no recorded instance in history of the sun having failed to rise on any morning.

So it would be stretching things for anyone to claim that because there was a rabbit in the box on Monday, that they knew there to be a rabbit in the box today - Thursday.

So I call the state ***delusion***.

Comment: Exactly my point! I tried to make that point regarding my answer of *in denial* but some people don't seem agree. But whatever, I am glad to see  that someone else here sees value in giving answers from different  perspectives.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[cognitive dissonance](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cognitive+dissonance)* if you are aware of the contradiction, or *[doublethink](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doublethink?s=t)* if you are unaware of any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would say they have the *wrong [impression](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/impression)* or that they *are [under the impression](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/under-the-impression-that?q=under+the+impression)* that the rabbit is in the box. But you wanted a single word so why not just say the person is *uninformed*, or *unaware*?

Comment: I don't understand why some answers without any sources cited or definitions offered earn up votes, or at least stay at 0, while other answers *on the same thread* will be voted down for no legitimate reason. Whatever... I fixed it, can someone please fix my negative score now? Or tell me how my answer is 'wrong', if not?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect your answer was downvoted because you didn't read the question carefully, so you answered a year-old question with a completely irrelevant answer. If you mistakenly think there is beer in the refrigerator because you bought some, but unknown to you somebody else drank it, you are ***not*** "in denial".

Comment: I don't think it is irrelevant, the person should have looked in the box again to verify what they believed was true. Avoiding being confronted with the truth is a form of denial so how is it irrelevant? Also, If the question is so old why is it appearing on the first page of recent questions results? Something wrong with the software or configuration if that is of concern.

Comment: If you think *in denial* is a good answer to the original question, I don't think you understand what *in denial* means in English.

Comment: I understand it perfectly well. What is the difference between that and  *cognitive dissonance*, which got voted up by the way.

Comment: I am not responsible for your downvote. I disagree with the upvote on *cognitive dissonance.* And I don't understand why you would knowningly give an bad answer to a question and expect to be upvoted.

Comment: I don't like having negative scores, okay? I updated my answer to make it fit the example given better, I just want my negative score negated. And I didn't *knowingly* give a bad answer, I simply answered the initial question without reading the example given. But I've corrected it now so I'd like my score corrected.

Comment: Someone here is in denial.  I'm not sure who to toss the life ring to, however.

Comment: Fine, tell me now what's wrong with the answer. If you approve, please zero me out.

Comment: @PeterShor What is wrong here is that the site allows people to cast anonymous down-votes. They irritate me too, simply because they are discourteous. Often, if I see one, I will do a compensatory up vote out of sympathy.

Comment: @Sk Johnson: The answer is good now. But in my opinion, anybody who answers the initial question without reading the example given deserves a downvote. Please don't do that in the future ... it's really disrespectful to the questioner if you don't actually read their question.  (But as I said, the downvote wasn't mine.)

Comment: Yes, I jumped then gun, I will be more careful. @WS2 Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I consider this "the state of false perception"

Comment: Hello, Sam, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Your view appears to be in line with Plato's—or rather, with the character Socrates'—in [his dialogue _Meno_](http://definitionofphilosophy.blogspot.com/2012/09/plato-true-belief-and-knowledge-in-meno.html), which attempts to distinguish 'truth' from 'true opinion' and 'false opinion.' I will gladly upvote your answer if you link it to some plausible discussion or argument in an authoritative source, but at the moment it reads simply as a personal opinion.

Comment: Ditto this comment to Mark?